# How to make 10 band equalizer on Android player if default is 5 band?

Tags: java, android, media-player, audio-player, equalizer, android-music-player

I am trying to make an android player and a problem occurred while making the equalizer. There is limit of equalizer bands, for example Nexus 5 has 5 band equalizer by default. Several players (such as Poweramp) somehow managed to get 10 band equalizer even on phones that have 5, 6 or 13 bands for example by default.

I am using Equalizer class to attach it to MediaPlayer and generally I understand how that works, but how to make 10 bands on phone that has by default only 5 bands?

So my question is how is this possible and how do some players manage to get 10 band equalizer on all phones, regardless of their system/hardware limit?

Comment: So you found out how to implement 10 bands?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Like you said frequency depends on hardware on a device. I tested with my Nexus 5 and it has 5 bands with these values:

- band 1: 30k-120k
- band 2: 120k-460k
- band 3: 460k-1.800k
- band 4: 1.800-7.000k
- band 5: 7.800k-1

You can get number of bands and presets with this code:

```
short numberOfBands = equalizer.getNumberOfBands();
short numberOfPresets = equalizer.getNumberOfPresets();
```

Frequency range of band you can get with this code:

```
final short minLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[0]; // get min range
final short maxLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[1]; // get max range
```

To show bends you do that like this:

```
for(short i = 0; i < numberOfBands; i++){
     SeekBar seekBar = ...
     mTextViewMin.setText(minLevel + "");
     mTextViewMax.setText(maxLevel + "");   
}
```

To initialize Equalizer:

```
Equalizer equalizer = new Equalizer(0, mediaplayer.getAudioSessionId());
equalizer.setEnabled(true);
```

Read more about equalizer here:
[Equalizer Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html)

Comment: so what are you trying to say? author knows how to get number of bands, you just wrote the same and didn't answer how to get 10 bands